# WalletSignTransactionError: encoding overruns Uint8Array

Tags: wallet, versionedtransactions

Context: I'm building a little feature on my app where users can close multiple ATA & perform swaps on jup protocol.
i have tried using regular tx but i have encountered the famous byte size limit.
Therefore i am trying to use the new VersionedTransaction, but unfortunately, i am getting the following error if the transaction gets "complicated".
[image: error]

```
WalletSignTransactionError: encoding overruns Uint8Array
```

env:

- angular
- wallet adapter

ideas?

Comment: Update your question with an example of a transaction that triggers this error. Use the `serialize` method and share it using https://gist.github.com